# Forcing particular notation for derivatives

Tags: output-formatting, formatting

I was wondering if it is possible to force particular style of displaying derivatives in Mathematica.

For example if I type: $$AB\partial_\mu C[\mu]$$

After execution it automatically be displayed as: $$ABC'(\mu)$$

I would prefer to have my derivatives with $\partial_\mu$ symbol for reasons. Is this possible?

Edit: Thanks for the reply Carl Woll. Such terms you written will never appear. What I want is to aesthetically have terms like $A^\mu\partial_\mu B$ and not $A^\mu B'$. Former case means something to me while the latter case requires one mental step to convert $'$ to derivative.

Comment: What do you want $AB\partial_\mu C[\mu + \nu]$ to look like?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to modify the formatting for [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative):

```
Derivative /: MakeBoxes[c'[x_], StandardForm] := MakeBoxes[D[c[x], x]]
```

For your example:

[image]

If you would rather have `c` instead of `c[μ]`, you could modify the above:

```
Derivative /: MakeBoxes[Derivative[1][c_][x_], StandardForm] := With[
    {boxes = MakeBoxes[D[c, x]]},
    InterpretationBox[boxes, Derivative[1][c][x]]
]
```

*(Here I use an InterpretationBox so that the output is copy/pasteable.)* Then:

[image]

However, in both cases, if the argument to c is not an index, then problems arise. For example:

[image]

Here is an alternative that doesn't require that you give arguments:

```
MakeBoxes[Dt[c_,x__], StandardForm] := With[{boxes = MakeBoxes[D[c,x]]},
    InterpretationBox[boxes, Dt[c,x]]
]
```

Then:

[image]

*(Note that the use of DifferentialD above has the alias <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>)* A few more examples:

[image]